# Can Google tech be trusted?

Tags: google, trust, nsa

With the Snowden leaks, Google has been implicated in the activities of the NSA.  There really is no way for ordinary citizens to know with certainty what the exact reality of this involvement is.  In my mind, that lack of certainty makes all Google tech suspect: anything "Google" could be tainted with unknown elements.

My question is: is that true?  Is it true that all Google tech is potentially un-trustworthy, or are there some things which can be considered separate and isolated from whatever mistrust one may hold for Google?  For instance: AngularJS.  Since that framework is open-source and non-binary, is it potentially "irrelevant" to any concerns over what Google's involvement with the NSA may or may not have been?

Can any of Google's tech be trusted, independently of whether or not one trusts Google itself?

Comment: I think you need to carefully read the question again. The question is of a technical nature. I'm not asking for opinions and the context of the question does not rely on holding any particular opinions. I asked about Google's tech and if any of it was immune from whatever mistrust of Google one may hold. I even gave an example of Angular (which I think probably is immune for the reasons I gave). So even if one does mistrust Google, Angular is still probably safe to use. Please read carefully when modding.